# Unable to get resource ID for Android view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I'm creating a custom `ListFragment` for my Android application. I want to add a child to `@id/listContainer`. But I'm not able to get the reference to the view using `findViewById(android.R.id.listContainer)`.

This is the default layout for `ListFragment`.

list_content.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/progressContainer"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:gravity="center">

        <ProgressBar style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/loading"
                android:paddingTop="4dip"
                android:singleLine="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/listContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/internalEmpty"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

This is my custom `ListFragment` code.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.list_content, container, false);

    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(getActivity());
    progressBar.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER));
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

    ViewGroup listContainer = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(android.R.id.listContainer);
    listContainer.addView(progressBar);

    return view;
}
```

Android Studio says `error: cannot find symbol variable listContainer`.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `getListView().getParent()`. since [getListView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html#getListView()) gives you the list view widget,it's parent should be the frame layout that you need.

Comment: Thanks @Droidekas. It solves the problem. But instead of calling `getListView()` I had to use `view.findViewById(android.R.id.list)`, since `getListView()` can't be called before the Fragment has finished its creation.

Comment: Why don't you use the onViewCreated method?

Comment: Yes. I can do that too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you are accessing resource:

```
ViewGroup listContainer = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(android.R.id.listContainer);
listContainer.addView(progressBar);
```

change it to

```
ViewGroup listContainer = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.listContainer);
listContainer.addView(progressBar);
```

**Since the `listContainer` is an internal resource, call it using**

```
com.android.internal.R.id.RESOURCE_ID
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Please note that `list_content.xml` is a file from the Android platform, it is not in my project.

Comment: **call com.android.internal.R.id.listContainer** to access the list container defined by the Android system

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :

```
  ViewGroup listContainer = 
                 (ViewGroup)view.findViewById(android.R.id.listContainer);
```

To

```
  ViewGroup listContainer = 
                 (ViewGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.listContainer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change  `View view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.list_content, container, false);`

To

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content, container, false);
```

Here `R` must be import `import com.your_package_name.R;`

Now you can change

`ViewGroup listContainer = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(android.R.id.listContainer);`

To

```
ViewGroup listContainer = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.listContainer);
```

Comment: No. I can't change that. `list_content` is an internal resource.